# React production build in a meteor app

Tags: reactjs, meteor, production

i have developped an application React/Redux with the Meteor JS framework.

The installation of React in meteor is class (npm command) :

> meteor npm install --save react

But when i check with the react-devtools extension, i see that React Version is the development build instead of production build.

(the message is "*This page is using the development build of React.*  ")

What have i to do to use the react production build instead in my meteor app ?
i already tried  to set environnement variables :

> export NODE_ENV='production'

but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Running the meteor with production flag e.g. `meteor --production` should mimic how the meteor app builds for production. To learn more about the deployment of the meteor apps read the meteor guide about [deployment and monitoring](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html).

Comment: This doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

this issue is solved with the Meteor version 1.5.1  (using the --production flag)

now i obtain this message :  This page is using the production build of React. ✅